# React/TypeScript - What does "Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>" stand for?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am writing Frontend Tests for React Components in TypeScript. Since the Code is from a more experienced Programmer, some Datatypes seem a bit new for me. Now I've got a prop that is defined with "Dispatch<SetStateAction>" as datatype. I've noticed that using the set-property of a useState-Hook is working, but I'm not really sure if this is how the prop is supposed to be used. For reference: The prop is called "onFullScreenClick". I'd be very grateful for an explanation and an example for what's most likely to be put in

Comment: "Code is from a more experienced Programmer" if they're still around, ask them! Mentoring juniors is literally part of their job description in most cases.

Answer (score 25):

If you look at the source of the typings:

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | (prevState: S) => S;

type Dispatch<A> = (action: A) => void;
```

`Dispatch` takes an action as a parameter and returns nothing meaningful (void).
There are multiple types of actions, and one of them is `SetStateAction`.

Remember that `useState` can take a new state, or a function that takes the previous state and returns the new state.

So `useState`'s type is actually:

```
type UseState<S> = (action: S | ((prevState: S) => S)) => void;
```

Comment: Awesome thx. Where can I find the sources for this ?

Comment: In the DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped GitHub repository, or in your editor you can probably choose "go to source".

Answer (score 6):

It's just a way telling typescript, the type of the props we are passing in

Take a look at this simply counter [example from sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-black-dqt6su?file=/src/App.tsx)

We have `const [num, setnum] = useState(0)` in the parent, and we pass both state and setter function to child component

The type of the `num` is infered from `useState(0)`, if we want the type of the setter function, we just hover mouse over it, and we get

`const setNum: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>`

and this `Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>` is the type of setter function.