# How to define type for createContext

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-typescript

Trying to learn typescript by migrating one of my old project to typescript.
Having trouble in defining type for the following Context-hook inside a React application.

`const authContext = createContext<IUser | {}[]>([{}, () => {}]);`

As you can see, I have used `<IUser | {}[]>` where,

```
interface IUser {
    name?: string;
    token?: string;
}
```

I am using the context like this:

```
function CheckAuth({ children }) {
  const [user] = useAuth();
  return (!user.name ? (<Navigate to='/login' />)
    : children
  );
}
```

where useAuth() is:

```
export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(authContext);
}
```

I am getting an error in `CheckAuth()` saying `Property 'name' doesn't exist on type {}`.

More info -

This is how the context is being declared in the React app.

```
function ProvideAuth({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | {}>({});
  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={auth}>
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is because when using `{}` there is no property so it throws an error when trying to acces `user.name` use `user?.name` instead, also

Comment: Also i think the definition of the type for your context is wrong
maybe you intended to do this `createContext<[IUser, DispatchIUser]>` where `DispatchIUser` is something similar to `type DispatchIUser = (user: Partial<IUser>) => void;` ? just some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete example based on the code in your question. I've included comments to explain in the code below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzgEwKYDMCGBXAG3hwGc4AlDHAYxgBoU5qoqYMBhCAOzYA97GMAJ5gMcACLASYHDGoALBqmGiKVWgFECGEBh5K4KsZRowAchEwGjcAMoYYtmLIwBBWsG4G8JDtz4CqD4YTi4MAL5wWFAQIHAA5Cym8QDcSEigkLCIcGY4AG7AAOYucJHRsQlJtAC0MXhsUDVosanpwDwYULjUYgCSAKq+UIiMXDi6APwAXHAkMFAdRWnKEADWejNzC0tp4ekA9AdwACryUoZ4YNpwABQ4UFA4QgCUhiJiFwDu8rLxZCwYHgoFwMGg4AAjIRwAAGwVCbAAPINhgA+GHTJA2FFdBFiAC8cAA2owcVADJJpLIFIj7I5nGx3DBPFxkUMuqjUQwALppJBHOAACS6GH+cHkEC+hggcA6wGZOAIwAAXmIYPIxNR-Bh+JitVx5nB8OrOJ1+HBCcxWH4zTA2cM8ajbkSEOE6Hc3vjUYhwtyXnysHguB5uHBgq4GvIPaNUIDgVww75TQF7pHkzqYP6kPt+ccTLQokGQwmteBuHoYGQfsAFEbqL0wPAFMACGgWFxc3BQWCjbDm632zC4GAYmB3qolRtDOcSJibOxzgO9AAFUdkQkIJiLtubWb58yWMThANF5mhhcYahrCPqu6b-s7hPhWYLluP1cQMAkF579QHzAxkw3CGkSwRQNyFqJm4ka3FmsYOPGdxgQAdOMuhwJMW5vu2cCzLciJ5IUJRsNK+LxAcBAQEUHTxHAByoi8WY5oGwZngmH6FJgN5Rrc97bjhz5wK+S5cB+X4-mophaDoFaAQKADiDjTmqVw3PcjzPG8cYgj2UKwvCDIYBijD6oaYF4pBBkuPaHK8eEWaMAKrhcOCpAkMUCbytKylAbaw4xJxXSwvkip4EZ-mfpi8FAiCdyMKgiLGvI6b8MhHHAJgIwhQQYX4gg5mGeEqLxagiAPu2+ylXAiIHElKUwGlAUZRyjBMUgQA)

```ts
import {
  default as React,
  createContext,
  type Dispatch,
  type ReactElement,
  type ReactNode,
  type SetStateAction,
  useContext,
  useState,
} from 'react';

import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

interface IUser {
  name?: string;
  token?: string;
}

// This tuple (array) type is what's returned by `useState<IUser>`:
type IUserState = [
  IUser,
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<IUser>>,
];

// Here's how to initialize the context:
const authContext = createContext<IUserState>([{}, () => {}]);

function useAuth () {
  return useContext(authContext);
}

// React function components which accept children
// need a `children` prop type like this:
type ChildrenProps = { children?: ReactNode };

function CheckAuth ({ children }: ChildrenProps): ReactNode {
  const [user] = useAuth();
  return (user.name ? children : (<Navigate to='/login' />));
}

function ProvideAuth ({ children }: ChildrenProps): ReactElement {
  // Get the tuple (array) returned by `useState`:
  const userState = useState<IUser>({});

  // And assign it to the context provider `value` prop:
  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={userState}>
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is so weird in contrast to how we write it in everything directly in javascript but it makes sense. We use the tuple to initialize the variables for useState, right? 

My code was a little weird (don't know what was going on in my head when I orginally wrote the code long ago) so I had to make slight changes because without them, it kept telling me that value prop had a different type than what it was being assigned.
The problem boiled down to string[] is not equal to [string]. 
Solved it though, so thanks for the elaborate explanation. Appreciate it.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976256/how-to-define-type-for-createcontext/73976666?noredirect=1#comment130619354_73976666) @ark_knight "_We use the tuple to initialize the variables for useState, right?_": You invoke the hook with the initial value and it returns a tuple. See [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) / [types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fcb0bdf0e20519bd7dbffbf5950c18753b0682b4/types/react/index.d.ts#L891-L905)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976256/how-to-define-type-for-createcontext/73976666?noredirect=1#comment130619425_73976666) So if you want to store everything that `useState` gives you, you have to initialize the context with the same (tuple) type.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing state and the setter for the state, the type should be:

```
const authContext = createContext<[IUser, Dispatch<SetStateAction<IUser>>]>([{}, () => {}]);
```

`Dispatch<SetStateAction<IUser>>` is the type of the setter, and if you want to know what exactly it is, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71324797/react-typescript-what-does-dispatchsetstateactionboolean-stand-for/71324882#71324882) was an answer about that.

---

Also, `{}` is not needed here:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>({});
```

This is fine since `IUser` has all its properties marked as optional.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nnb6vN)

Comment: I think I might have done this and come across another problem.. I edited the Playground link, can you see the changes or how do I share the link?

Comment: Heyo, thanks! Solved it with some explanation from the other comment. Was having problem with the type casting of value prop in Provider but his playground along with yours gave me enough hint to solve the problem. Appreciate the help!