# How to store data from GraphQL response in sessionStorage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I'm trying to save my GraphQL response in sessionStorage, so I get access to it in several places and I don't need to make an API call more then once. The problem is, I'm not sure how am I supposed to do this. I'm trying to use useQuery hook with skip property where I check if sessionStorage.getItem("ITEM") exists or not, if not - set it, then check again. I think it's not the best practice and I'm pretty sure that there is something better I could do.

Here's the hook which I'm trying to make as reusable, to check if sessionStorage exists and optionally save it.

```
export const useGetClientQuery = () => {
  let { data: clientList, loading } = useQuery<any>(getClientsQuery(), {
    client: ApiClient.configGraphqlClient,
    skip: sessionStorage.getItem("clientsList") ? true : false,
  });

  if (clientList) sessionStorage.setItem("clientsList", JSON.stringify(clientList));

  const clientListJSON = sessionStorage.getItem("clientsList");

  return { clientListJSON };
};
```

and this is an example how I'm trying to use it:

```
  const { clientListJSON } = useGetClientQuery();

  const clientList = JSON.parse(clientListJSON); // I'm working with typescript, which shows an error: Argument of type 
'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of 
type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

and I know why this is happening but I don't really know how to do it differently. Looking for some good advices :)

Comment: Are you using a graphQL client by chance?

Answer (score 1):

> so I get access to it in several places

Just use the state provided by the query result in every component that needs it<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup> <sup>3</sup>.

> and I don't need to make an API call more then once

The `useQuery` hook supports a [`staleTime`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery#:%7E:text=staleTime%3A) option that — if set to `Infinity` — configures the value to be cached for the lifetime of the JS execution context (session): so subsequent invocations will just return the cached value instead of re-fetching.

Check out the [documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery)!

---

<sup>1</sup> [React docs - Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

<sup>2</sup> [React docs beta - Sharing State Between Components](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

<sup>3</sup> [React docs beta - Passing Data Deeply with Context](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)

Comment: I can't pass it through a component tree, these components are not connected to each other and I can't provide it as a props between them. For now I do not want to use store like Redux or MobX neither.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74031627/how-to-store-data-from-graphql-response-in-sessionstorage/74031930#comment130715759_74031930) @larryfisherman Well, that's a different question than the one you asked, and has certainly already been covered on this site (see [What is a duplicate question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)). [Here's one version of it that I answered earlier this week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73976666/438273). You can also search on SO for things like [`react state context`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=react+state+context).

Comment: @larryfisherman I added another link to the React beta docs which cover the state-in-context pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`useQuery` is meant to be used as a hook in a react component. You should see that `loading` is `true` for awhile until `data` is returned.

Try using `await client.query()` where `client` is your `ApolloClient` object.

You might find local storage even more useful than session storage since it also survives a page refresh which neither session nor a prop at a higher level would.