# Updating object in global state array typescript react

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I have been trying some days to figure out how to update my global state array in a gis-project. I use Mapbox-gl with ts and react. I use the useContext hook to keep track of a list of "GeoJSONItems", which includes a geoJSON object and some metadata. However, several ts problems occur when I try to update the global array.`your text`

This is my GeoJSONContext.tsx

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { FeatureCollection } from "geojson";

export type GeoJSONItem = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  visable: boolean,
  color: string,
  geoJSON: FeatureCollection;
};

type GeoJSONContextType = {
  geoJSONList: Array<GeoJSONItem>;
  setGeoJSONList: (selected: GeoJSONItem[]) => void;
  setVisable: (value: boolean) => void;
};

const GeoJSONContext = createContext<GeoJSONContextType>({
  geoJSONList: [],
  setGeoJSONList: () => {},
  setVisable: () => {}
});

export const useGeoJSONContext = () => useContext(GeoJSONContext);

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

const GeoJSONProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [geoJSONList, setGeoJSONList] = useState<GeoJSONItem[]>([]);
  const [visable, setVisable] = useState<boolean>(); 


  return (
    <GeoJSONContext.Provider value={{ geoJSONList, setGeoJSONList, setVisable }}>
      {children}
    </GeoJSONContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default GeoJSONProvider;
```

This is how global states should be handled with useContext (Works for local arrays) and how I try in my components:

`setGeoJSONs((prevGeoJSONs) => [...prevGeoJSONs, json as FeatureCollection]);`

I have managed to work it out with Array.push(), but I know its not a good practice working with global states.

So, when calling the global setGeoJSONList, when adding an Object or updating it:

`setGeoJSONList((prevGeoJSONs) => [...prevGeoJSONs, json as FeatureCollection]);`

ts sends this error: Argument of type '(prevGeoJSONs: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GeoJSONItem[]'
As if it dosen't understand that prevGeoJSONs is an array of GEOJSONItem.
Note:

- I have tried casting it as GeoJSONItem[] with ts syntax and with "as GeoJSONItem[]"
- It works for adding one object but it requires sometimes that I have to add several and then the list would be overwritten.

Hope somebody have time to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared `setGeoJSONList` as type `(selected: GeoJSONItem[]) => void` - in other words, it only takes an actual array of items.

However, you're trying to use it by passing it a function that produces an array of items:

```
setGeoJSONList((prevGeoJSONs) => [...prevGeoJSONs, json as FeatureCollection]);
```

The setter that's returned by `useState<GeoJSONItem[]>` can take either a value or a function that produces a value; in other words, it's of type `(selected: GeoJSONItem[] | ((prevSelected: GeoJSONItem[]) => GeoJSONItem[])) => void`. TypeScript understands this as long as you're using `useState`'s return value directly, but when you then pass it to a context property that's explicitly typed as `(selected: GeoJSONItem[]) => void`, it requires only the array format.

Changing the type of your producer function should fix this.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71324797/25507).

Comment: It worked!! I did not know of this nature of useState, thank you very much Josh!